# Is it possible to search the developer toolbox on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I can't find a way to search inside the developer toolbox (menu that appears when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>).

Or is it not possible to search there at all?

I'm on Firefox v79 if that helps.

[image: Firefox Developer Toolbox]

Comment: Are you trying to search the `menu.css` file?

Comment: No, I'm trying to search all of the files.

Comment: I don't think that's possible..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search something across multiple style sheets in the Style Editor, that's not possible, unfortunately (as of Firefox 87). You may want to follow the [feature request for it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=889571), though.

In the Style Editor you can only search within the currently selected style sheet. To do that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (macOS) to open the search field, enter what you want to search for and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The search field closes automatically, though you can toggle through all matches by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (macOS).

If you mean to search across different network resources, you may want to use the [search feature there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_list#search_in_requests).